# I have a XML document with several tags,values,Now I want to interchange/swap two tags completely how can I achieve this?

Tags: xml

1.

```
<SubjectClassification Authority="AP Subject" AuthorityVersion="5577" System="Teragram" SystemVersion="1">
    <Occurrence ActualMatch="true" Id="b2a4c0a08315100485d9d5a57deba703" ParentId="17956128897810048ce8d56c852d093e" Value="Arrests"/>
</SubjectClassification>
```

2.

```
<SubjectClassification Authority="AP Subject" AuthorityVersion="5577" System="Teragram" SystemVersion="1">
    <Occurrence ActualMatch="true" Id="b2a4c0a08315100485d9d5a57deba703" ParentId="48612b807c2b4b93bbbacbf54f547ad5" Value="Arrests"/>
</SubjectClassification>
```

Here there are two tags starting with subject classification and I have named it as 1) and 2). Now I want to interchange two tags . Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your XML in your question, not as an image,

Comment: what do you want to change? Can you post the output you want to have?

Comment: Actually I want to compare two XML files, which will contain many say some 10 subject classification tags, and I am having an attribute Authority Version with different values in jumbled manner in both the files I want to compare, So I want to keep one file as a constant and in other I want to re-arrange tags and then need to compare with the constant one. So I want to interchange/Swap tags for that reason